# Hotkey to restore current File Explorer windows?

Tags: windows-explorer, hotkeys

Is there a hotkey to restore all current File Explorer windows in Windows 10?

For example if you are working between the File Explorer and other applications and need to minimize them repeatedly, then re-maximize them to their previous locations?

There is the hotkey to create a new window (Windows + E), is there something similar to re-open the current windows?

Comment: Alt + Tab opens a preview mode to select current File Explorer windows from but is it possible to just expand all of the current File Explorer windows with one hotkey?

Comment: I think you mean "restore" not "expand". Please [edit] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Windows + D] to minimize all openning windows, then [Windows + D] again to restore them.

Or you can try [Alt + Space, then N] to minimize a windows, then [Alt + Tab] or [Windows + Tab] to choose and restore it.

Hope this help!